# Wait time after change slicer in power pivot

Tags: excel, powerpivot, vba

I have a powerpivot table and one slicer with several values. I have a macro that loops over my slicer and makes a copy of the data and paste the values in another excel

After any data update when I change the slicer Excel takes some time to query or recalculate values and in the cells appear  "#######" during some seconds until the the new data are loaded.

This is a problem for my macro because it is copying this characters instead of the values. I have try two approaches to give more time to the loading process:

- Create a Wait of 5 seconds that is more than enough before copy-pasting the data
- Put a Msgbox to stop the copy pasting.

None of them work. Both of them seems to interrupt the loading process that I though will run in the background.

Is there any event in vba that notifies me when the data are loaded?

Comment: I suspect you want to add `Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone` before you copy the table.

Comment: If you should share parts of your code to look at...

Comment: That's it Rory, thanks

Comment: You should also add Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic before your Async command, otherwise it seems to hang for ever if it's on manual calculation.  You can set it back to xlCalculationManual afterwards as a neat 3 lines of code.

Comment: An additional word of warning: I think if you use CUBESET, then Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone seems to hang for ever.  It may be recalculating the entire model???  You can't escape from this command either -- Excel stops responding completely and you have to kill it.  So use with care.

Answer (score 0):

For those who can't use CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone because it hangs indefinitely, I devised a solution for this.  It's blunt but it works.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40792389/1540567